# Let $L(i,j) = a_i^\mathsf{T} a_j$, How to write this?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of vectors $a_i\in R^d,i\in [1,..,n]$. Then we have $L(i,j) = a_i^\mathsf{T} a_j$.

My questions are

1- How to write $L$, using matrices or vectors, not element by element like above?

2- Assume, $L_v(i,j)= a_i^\mathsf{T} R_v^{-1} a_j$, where $R_v$ is a symmetric matrix. What is $L_v^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $\text{row}_iA$ as the $i$th row of matrix $A$ and $\text{col}_iA$ as the $i$th column of matrix $A$. We notice following proposition

> **Proposition 1.** Let $A$ be $n\times m$ matrix, $B$ be $m \times n$ matrix then the $(i,j)$-th entry of $AB$ equals product of $i$-th row of $A$ and the $j$-th column of $B$. In formulas: $(AB)_{i,j}=\text{row}_iA \cdot \text{col}_jB.$

For (1), if we let matrix $A= (a_1 \; a_2 \; \cdots \; a_n)$ then $\text{col}_jA=a_j$ and $\text{row}_i A^T=a_i^T$. Hence, $L_{i,j}=\text{row}_i A^T \cdot \text{col}_jA$ for all $1 \le i,j \le n$. Hence, according to the proposition, we find $L=A^TA$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

For (2), denote matrix $B=(R_v^{-1}a_1 \; R_v^{-1}a_2 \; \cdots \; R_v^{-1}a_n)$ then similarly, we find $L_v=A^TB$. On the other hand, note that $B_{i,j}=\text{row}_i R_v^{-1} \cdot a_j=\text{row}_i R_v^{-1} \cdot \text{col}_jA$ so according to the proposition, we have $B=R_v^{-1}A$. Thus, $L_v=A^T R_v^{-1}A$. Hence, $L_v^{-1}=A^{-1}R_v(A^T)^{-1}$.

I haven't used the condition that $R_v$ is symmetric. Do you have any further requirement for $L_v^{-1}$, or the above answer is good enough?